# Medical term for headbanging inability post-car-crash condition

Tags: terminology, head-trauma, vehicle-car-accident, temples, range-of-motion

I would like to know the name of the brain (sub)condition whereby after a car accident, you are unable to shake your head in vigorous back and forth or side to side headbanging activity head movements (such as those taking part among youth listening to heavy metal music in a group).

When the brain is shaken, some brain-specific pain is felt at the peripheral areas of the brain, where the car crash pressure of the brain against the skull bones took place.

Anyways, no big deal if you don't have a specific term for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the context of pain when rapidly moving the head **after** a car accident, one should look into wether you have a [Concussion](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000799.htm). A concussion is an altered functioning state of the brain after a traumatic event that made it move and swell within your skull.

Naturally, I strongly recommend seeing a doctor ASAP if this has recently appeared or gotten worse recently, or if you weren't diagnosed.

Comment: He didn't ask for a diagnosis. He asked for the medical term for a condition.

Comment: Ok. Nausea or headache... due to a concussion.